# Get largest image from Facebook graph api photo node

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the facebook graph api v2.6.  I'm accessing the photo's of a user via "me/photos?fields=images".  This provides an array of various sizes of the given photo.  Obviously I could just run through the list and pick the largest one but I wanted to know if there is a way to limit the results returned to the largest one to reduce the payload size since I only care about the highest resolution one.

Also, please note that "type=normal" does not return the largest image (nor does it seem to work on the photos node anyway) and the "source" field is not the largest image either and that field is depreciated anyway.  Thanks.

Update: please note I am not trying to access the profile image of a user, I am trying to access the photos node of the user which is all of the photos they have been tagged in.  Here is the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user/photos

It returns a list of photos as documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/

The various sized images are in the "images" field and I want to know if I can restrict that to just the largest image.  It doesn't appear so in the documentation but Facebook's documentation has been historically lacking...

Answer (score -1):

You want get a picture for a Facebook User?

Try this way

```
https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/picture?type=large
```

Comment: No, sorry, I'm trying to access the photos graph node "me/photos", not the user's profile picture.  The photo's node is all pictures the user is tagged in.

Comment: Ok, the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/) the documentation there is nothing about the size of. Maybe there is some hook.